# Access JSON values using Chef and test-kitchen

Tags: json, chef-infra, test-kitchen

I'm new to Chef and Test-kitchen and I'm trying to use random JSON file as attribute or environment (preferably attribute), but unfortunately I can't access the JSON values from the recipes.

I'm using the following directory structure:

```
uat
├── attributes
│   ├── dev.json
│   ├── .kitchen
│   │   └── logs
│   │       └── kitchen.log
│   └── prod.json
├── Berksfile
├── Berksfile.lock
├── chefignore
├── environments
│   ├── dev.json
│   └── prod.json
├── Gemfile
├── Gemfile.lock
├── .kitchen
│   ├── default-windows.yml
│   └── logs
│       ├── default-windows.log
│       └── kitchen.log
├── .kitchen.yml
├── metadata.rb
└── recipes
    ├── default.rb
    ├── prep.rb
    └── service_install.rb
```

This is the ***.kitchen.yml***:

```
---
driver:
  name: machine
  username: sample_user
  password: sample_pass
  hostname: 192.168.1.102
  port: 5985

provisioner:
  name: chef_zero
  json_attributes: true
  environments_path: 'environments/dev'

platforms:
  - name: windows

suites:
  - name: default
    run_list:
      - recipe[uat::default]
```

This is the ***dev.json***:

```
{
    "groupID": "Project-name",
    "directoryName": "sample_folder",
    "environmentType": "UAT",
}
```

This is the recipe ***prep.rb*** :

```
directory "C:/Users/test/#{node['directoryName']}" do
  recursive true
  action :create
end
```

If I create *something.rb* in attributes folder and with content: default['directoryName'] = 'sample_folder', it works like a charm, but I need to use a JSON file which to store parameters company wide.

Could you please help me find what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

So a couple of issues. First, the `environments_path` points at a folder, not the specific file, so that should just be `environments/`. Second, it has to be an actual environment object, see https://docs.chef.io/environments.html#json for a description of the schema. Third, you would need to actually apply the environment to the test node:

```
provisioner:
  # Other stuff ...
  client_rb:
    chef_environment: dev
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked well.
Is there a way to use the JSON without using the default_argument:
`{
  "default_attributes": {
    }
}`

Comment: No, you have to match the schema of the environment object.